# I don't know if this is an awkward usage of "for which" and an adjective

Tags: word-choice, grammar

> The figure of casualties is presumed to be significantly higher, but there are no specific data *for which* published.

The latter part of the sentence sounds a little awkward to me.  I just want to know if it is grammatically correct.

Comment: It is not grammatically correct, no. It also doesn't make any sense whatsoever. It looks like either A) there's half a sentence missing [“there are no specific data for which published material can reliably account” or something along those lines]; or B) _for which_ just shouldn't be there at all [“there are no specific data published” alone works fine]. If it's the latter, a better phrasing would be, “but no specific data have been published”. If it's neither, you'll have to tell us what it's supposed to mean, ’cause it's gibberish as it is.

Comment: Can you hyperlink it to the original source? I don't believe this makes any sense, however, if there's context around this sentence, I can judge whether this is indeed completely wrong.

Comment: This is actually a part of an essay, and if I were to hyperlink it, you would have to read a lot of text.  Would that be too much of a burden to any of you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does sounds awkward to me.

Personally, depending on the surrounding bits, I'd word it more like

> ...significantly higher, but no data on the discrepancy has been published.

if expected data will dispute another report or

> ...significantly higher, but no definite data has been published.

if you're saying higher than previously assumed. I'm not an expert though.